# Renaming elements within a .properties file using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to rename an element inside a application.properties file using C#. 
This is currently being accomplished via a batch file but it would be good if I could directly acheive this with C#.

For example inside my application.properties file I have the value 'name'. 
With a batch file which is being run from within C# I can update the element 'name' in this file on the fly.

Im assuming there is a way to accomplish this in C# without the need for a batch file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Comment: Try breaking down your problem into smaller steps, have a go at each, and come back with your specific problems. For example - open file, parse file, modify file contents, save file. Once you've had a go you'll either have nailed it (yay), or you'll know specifically what your problem is.

Comment: Can you add an example of what the .properties file looks like to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this using BinaryWriter.

```
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(ApppropFile, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            //write new data
            string strNewData = "NEW DATA";
            byte[] byteNewData = new byte[strNewData.Length];

            // copy contents of string to byte array
            for (var i = 0; i < strNewData.Length; i++)
            {
                byteNewData[i] = Convert.ToByte(strNewData[i]);
            }

            // write new data to file
            bw.Seek(141, SeekOrigin.Begin);  // seek to position 


            bw.Write(byteNewData, 0, byteNewData.Length);
        }
```

Comment: FWIW, seeking to a specific location is brittle. Unless your .properties file absolutely never changes, this code will start behaving erratically when position 141 no longer means what it does now.

Comment: The properties file never changes and the above example only needs to change the data at position 141 in my case. I can understand how if the properties file dynamically changes or multiple bytes need changing this would be an issue!

Comment: No worries, wanted to call it out just in case. Glad you got it working!